# Split attribute labels with delimiter for processing

Tags: weka, kaggle

I opened a csv file in Weka 3.8 and selected an attribute/column (picture below). The labels are delimited by a pipe character. There should be 23 distinct labels but Weka displays 914. Thus, Weka cannot visualize for too many values. Action is one label, adventure is another one, etc. Basically there can be more than one label per row.

For processing (eg. classification), How can separate those values so Weka can read them?

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772114/multiple-values-for-one-weka-attribute). But the question asks about the date attribute (eg. "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"). This asks about a character-separated value (eg. "Action|Adventure|Drama")

[image: selected attribute with labels delimited by |]

Edit:
The data is taken from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/sohier/getting-imdb-kernels-working-with-tmdb-data/).

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I had run into this problem too.

Firstly, ensure that the Genres attribute is recognised as a String type. If you are only using the GUI, go to `Open File...` and open the file (I presume it's a `.dat` file. If you've renamed it to `.csv` hit the check box which says "Invoke options dialog").

[image: Invoke options dialog check box]

In the Generic Object Editor window, enter the index of the Genres attribute (here it's **last**).

[image: Edit the stringAttributes field]

Doing that will cause the attribute to look like this in the GUI.

[image: Neither numeric nor nominal]

Now choose the filter called StringToWordVector (`weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector`). Now under the Editor window, find the **Tokenizer** entry, click on its field, and under **delimeters** remove the defaults and add the pipe character. You may optionally edit the attribute prefix field as well.

[image: Edit the delimiter entry.]

Hit apply and find the required genres added in as **numeric** attributes, set to 0 for cases where the genre was not present in the original string, 1 otherwise.

[image: New attributes added into the fray]

`StringToWordVector` is a pretty useful filter, and there's much more to it in the docs: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html.

Comment: You may also use the Relational type (it's in here https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/arff_stable/) by directly editing the text, and the `RELAGGS` filter (http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.packages/multiInstanceFilters/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RELAGGS.html), although I think you'd need to install it using the package manager. By far, the `StringToWordVector` approach looked easiest, so here it is.